# Using $scope in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a simple problem that I can't seem to figure out. I am new to angular.js and am trying ui.router. My web application is a table that displays JSON data.

The columns are all of the keys in a single JSON object, and the rows are the values for each respective key. I would like to do something like the following:

```
go to www.xyz.com/keyname,
```

and see all of the values for keyname.

However, I got stuck in trying to get the keys.

The keys are defined in a controller which is passed the data via a factory. I was then thinking I would do something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('SortingTables', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']);


app.factory('dataTable', function () {
           return tastyJSONData;
      });

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'dataTable', function ($scope, dataTable) {
     $scope.dataTable = dataTable;
     $scope.columns = the keys in dataTable;
}]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

    // pseudocode

    for every column in $scope.columns in Ctrl
        $stateProvider.state(column)...
}]);
```

However, I can't access the scope within the controller which contains the data. Am I missing something?

The config runs before the factory, so how can I access the data made by the factory in my config?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is best practice to keep all logic within the controller. Maybe go for something along the lines of:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$stateProvider', 'dataTable', function ($scope, $stateProvider, dataTable) {
   $scope.dataTable = dataTable;
   $scope.columns = the keys in dataTable;

   // pseudocode

   for every column in $scope.columns
       $stateProvider.state(column)...
}]);
```

And then just leave your config for routing purposes

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider',function ($urlRouterProvider) {

    //routing
}]);
```

Hard to say for sure without complete code. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think defining explicit states is making things harder than is required.

Try something like this:

```
.state('keys', {
    url: '/',
    resolve: {
        keys: ['$http', function($http {
            return $http.get('/api/keys');
        }]
    },
    controller: function($scope, keys) {
        $scope.allKeys = keys;
    }
})

.state('keys.detail', {
    url: '/:keyname',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.keyname = $stateParams.keyname;
    }
})
```

and in your view for 'keys' state something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="keyname in allKeys">
    <a ui-sref="keys.detail({keyname: keyname})">{{ keyname }}</a>
</li>
```